# How do I make GraphQL wait for posts from a separate repo?

Tags: gatsby

I have my blog posts in a separate repo from the structure of the site.

This separates commits for the site code from commits for content updates. People could also submit pull requests for error corrections on blog posts.

I am using the NPM package [download-git-repo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/download-git-repo) The first time I run `gatsby build` it seems the posts aren't loaded before GraphQL is trying to work with them.

`GraphQLError: Cannot query field "allMarkdownRemark" on type "Query".`

Running `gatsby build` a second time does not return an error.

---

Lines 3-5 in gatsby-node.js are my code for importing the blog posts repo.

How can I write this code so that the posts will load before GraphQL is looking for them?

```
const path = require('path')
const { createFilePath, createFileNode } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)
const download = require('download-git-repo')

download('jastuccio/blog-posts', 'src/pages/blog-posts', function(err) {
  console.log(err ? 'Error' : 'Success')
})

exports.createPages = ({ actions, graphql }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const blogPostTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/blog-post.js`)

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(
      graphql(`
        {
          allMarkdownRemark(
            sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] }
            limit: 1000
          ) {
            edges {
              node {
                fields {
                  slug
                }
                frontmatter {
                  title
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `).then(result => {
        if (result.errors) {
          console.log(result.errors)
          return reject(result.errors)
        }

        const blogTemplate = path.resolve('./src/templates/blog-post.js')

        result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
          createPage({
            path: node.fields.slug,
            component: blogTemplate,
            context: {
              slug: node.fields.slug,
            }, // additional data can be passed via context
          })
        })
        return
      })
    )
  })
}

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions
  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: `pages` })
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `slug`,
      value: slug,
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps ‘download’ is happening asynchronously, so by the time gatsby runs, the blog data isn’t there yet?

You should download the repo in [`onPreBootstrap` hook](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#onPreBootstrap). This happens before gatsby start to read config from plugin & build data for the site.

Maybe something like

```
// gatsby-node.js

exports.onPreBootstrap = () => new Promise(( res, rej ) => {
  download(‘...’, ‘...’, (err) => {
    if (err) rej(err);
    else res();
  })
})
```